# How to access the row of a datatable that corresponds to the selected item in a datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

So ive got a datatable that gets filled with an sql query and is set as the itemsource for a datagrid. i want to find the selected item on the datagrid in the datatable and add it to a new one.. I'm sorry i know it's probably a stupid simple question i just cant wrap my head around it, im assuming if i could find the index of the selected item i could use that to access a datatable.rows[x], however in my case the user is filtering the items in the datagrid so that would have to be looked up in the corresponding dataview i create in order to do the text filtering.

```
    private void btnAddPart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (DataRowView)dgParts.SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            DataRow row = item.Row;
            dtDocParts.ImportRow(row);
        }


        dgDocParts.ItemsSource = dtDocParts.AsDataView();
    }
```

With help from the below answer I was able to write this method that does what I need. NOTE that I had to use ImportRow and not Rows.Add as that would give you an error because a row cant belong to more than one table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataGrid.SelectedItem property. It has `object` type, so you need to cast it to concrete type of item in ItemsSource. In this case it will be DataRowView, because ItemsSource is DataView object.

DataRowView contains all values for one row, which are accessible by column name or index, but also has a reference to original row:

```
var item = (DataRowView)dgDocParts.SelectedItem;
if (item != null)
{
   object cellValue1 = item[0];
   object cellValue2 = item["columnName"];
   DataRow row = item.Row;
}
```